# composition of Lebesgue integrable function with smooth function

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

If I have a function $f\in L^{1}_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ and I compose it with 
$g:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ which is smooth.
Then is it always true that $f\circ g\in L^{1}_{loc}(\mathbb{R^2})$?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no. Try $f (x) = |x|^{-\delta} $ for a suitable $\delta >0$ and $g (x_1, x_2) = x_1^{2n} $ for a large $n \in \Bbb {N} $ (depending on $\delta $).

Comment: thank you. If I take for example $g(x,y)=x-y$ then the answer is true right?(by changing variables in the integral)

Comment: @lisa: Not really by changing variables, but by Fubini's theorem and translation invariance. It suffices to show integrability over $[-R,R]^2$ for every $R>0$. We have $\int_{[-R,R]^2} |f(g(x,y))| \,d(x,y) = \int_{-R}^R \int_{-R}^R |f(x-y)| \, dx \, dy = \int_{-R}^R \int_{-R-y}^{R-y}|f(x)|\, dx \, dy\leq \int_{-R}^R \int_{-2R}^{2R} |f(x)| \, dx \, dy <\infty$ since $f \in L^1_{loc}$. Note that it was essential that we got a bound on the inner integral independent of $y$.